# How do I get a `BindingExpression` from a `Binding` object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

In short(?), I have a `ListView` (target) one-way bound to an `XmlDataProvider` (source) two-way bound to a `TextBox` (target) using standard XAML for the control bindings and custom XAML extensions for the bindings to the `XmlDataProvider`.  This is a convenience for the application as the `XmlDataProvider` is dynamically loaded from user inputs after the application is running,...

Anyway, at run-time, after modifying the `TextBox.Text` property, the `IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack(...)` method is called to propagate the update from this target back to the source.  But, because the `XmlDataProvider` object is not a `DependencyProperty`, the update is not further propagated from the changed `XmlDataProvider` source to the other binding to the `ListView` target.

Without rearchitecting, which you could legitimately advise, I need to notify WPF that any target with this `XmlDataProvider` as a source needs to be updated.  I am hoping to maintain a generic, reusable binding class and have, so far, enjoyed the low coding burden of my mostly XAML solution.

Currently, the only code behind access I have is from within the `IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack(...)` method.  From within this method I do have access to the `Binding` object for the `XmlDataProvider` <--> `TextBox` link.  If I could get the `BindingExpression` for the `Binding.Source` object I could then make the call to `BindingExpression.UpdateTarget()` to complete the update propagation,...

But, I do not know how to get a `BindingExpression`from a `Binding.Source` object, that is not associated with a `DependencyProperty`.

Thanks in advance for your advice and assistance.

Comment: the only way you can do this is using the method `Binding.ProvideValue` (this actually returns a `BindingExpression`), but that method requires some `IServiceProvider` as argument. The only where I've seen we can access to such interface is inside the `ProvideValue` implementation of some custom `MarkupExtension`. So looks like it's really stuck there.

Comment: It is an avenue that I was unaware of and worth a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom `MarkupExtension` which accepts a `Binding` as a constructor argument. In XAML usage, yours will be an outer binding that wraps the WPF one:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb" />
    <TextBlock Text="{local:MyBinding {Binding ElementName=tb,Path=Text,Mode=OneWay}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the `MyBinding` constructor you will receive a WPF `Binding` object. Store a copy for later when your `ProvideValue` is called. At that time, you can call `ProvideValue` on the binding you saved--and **pass it the IServiceProvider instance you now have**. You'll get back a `BindingExpression` that you can then return from *your own* `ProvideValue`.

Here's a minimal example. For a simple demonstration, it just adds (or overwrites) a `Binding.StringFormat` property to the inner (wrapped) binding.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(BindingExpression))]
public sealed class MyBindingExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public MyBindingExtension(Binding b) { this.m_b = b; }

    Binding m_b;

    public override Object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        m_b.StringFormat = "---{0}---";   // modify wrapped Binding first...

        return m_b.ProvideValue(sp);    // ...then obtain its BindingExpression
    }
}
```

If you try it with the XAML above, you'll see that a live binding is indeed set on the target, and you didn't have to unpack the `IProvideValueTarget` at all.

This covers the basic insight, so if you know exactly what to do now, you probably won't need to read the rest of this answer...

---

**More details**

In most cases, digging into the `IProvideValueTarget` is actually the point of the whole exercise, because you can then **modify the wrapped binding dynamically** according to runtime conditions. The expanded `MarkupExtension` below shows the extraction of the relevant objects and properties, and there are obviously numerous possibilities for what you can do from there.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(BindingExpression))]
[ContentProperty(nameof(SourceBinding))]
public sealed class MyBindingExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public MyBindingExtension() { }
    public MyBindingExtension(Binding b) => this.b = b;

    Binding b;
    public Binding SourceBinding
    {
        get => b;
        set => b = value;
    }

    public override Object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        if (b == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(SourceBinding));

        if (!(sp is IProvideValueTarget pvt))
            return null;                // prevents XAML Designer crashes

        if (!(pvt.TargetObject is DependencyObject))
            return pvt.TargetObject;    // required for template re-binding

        var dp = (DependencyProperty)pvt.TargetProperty;

        /*** INSERT YOUR CODE HERE ***/

        // finalize binding as a BindingExpression attached to target
        return b.ProvideValue(sp);
    }
};
```

For completeness, this version can also be used with `XAML` object tag syntax, where the wrapped `Binding` is set as a property, instead of in the constructor.

Insert your customization code for manipulating the binding where indicated. You can do pretty much anything you want here, such as:

1. Check or modify the runtime situation and/or state:

```
var x = dobj.GetValue(dp);
dobj.SetValue(dp, 12345);
dobj.CoerceValue(dp); // etc.
```

2. Reconfigure and/or customize the binding prior to sealing it into the `BindingExpression`:

```
b.Converter = new FooConverter(/* customized values here */);
b.ConverterParameter = Math.PI;
b.StringFormat = "---{0}---";   // ...as shown above
```

3. Perhaps decide binding is not needed in certain cases; do not proceed with binding:

```
if (binding_not_needed)
    return null;
```

4. Lots more, limited by your imagination. When ready, call the binding's `ProvideValue` method and it will create its `BindingExpression`. Because you pass it your own `IProvideValueTarget` info (i.e. your `IServiceProvider`), the new binding will substitute itself for your markup extension. It gets attached to the target object/property where *your* `MarkupExtension` was authored in XAML, which is exactly what you want.

**Bonus: You can also manipulate the returned BindingExpression**

If pre-configuring the binding isn't enough, note that you also have access to the instantiated `BindingExpression`. Instead of [tail-calling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) the `ProvideValue` result as shown, just store the result into a local. Prior to returning it, you can set up monitoring or interception of the binding traffic via the various notification options that are available on `BindingExpression`.

---

Final note: as discussed [here](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/08/23/wpf-markup-extensions-and-templates/), there are special considerations when WPF markup extensions are used inside **templates**. In particular, you will notice that your markup extension is initially probed with `IProvideValueTarget.TargetObject` set to an instance of `System.Windows.SharedDp`. Because loading templates is a naturally a deferred process, I believe the purpose here is **early probing of your markup extension** to determine its characteristics, i.e. long prior to the existence of any real data which could populating the template properly. As shown in the above code, you [<strike>must return 'this'</strike>] c̲a̲n̲ r̲e̲t̲u̲r̲n̲ t̲h̲e̲ p̲r̲o̲b̲e̲ o̲b̲j̲e̲c̲t̲ i̲t̲s̲e̲l̲f̲ for these cases; <strike>if you don't, your `ProvideValue` won't be called back again when the real `TargetObject` is available</strike> [see edit].

---

**edit:** WPF tries really hard to make XAML resources shareable, and this especially includes the `BindingBase` and derived classes. If using the technique I describe here in a reusable context (such as a `Template`), you need to make sure that the wrapped binding does not meet the criteria for shareability, otherwise the wrapped binding will become `BindingBase.isSealed=true` after the first time it generates a `BindingExpression`; subsequent attempts to modify the `Binding` will fail with:

> InvalidOperationException: Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.

There are several workarounds to do this, which you can ascertain by studying the source code of the (non-public) WPF function [TemplateContent.TrySharingValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/TemplateContent.cs,46c60e62068b4a90). One method I found was to return the `System.Windows.SharedDp` object from your markup extension anytime it shows up. You can detect `System.Windows.SharedDp` either by looking for any non-`DependencyObject` value, or more specifically as follows:

```
if (pvt.TargetObject.GetType().Name == "SharedDp")
   return pvt.TargetObject;
```

(Technically, checking for `.GUID` value `{00b36157-dfb7-3372-8b08-ab9d74adc2fd}` instead would the most correct). I've updated the code in my original post to reflect this, but I welcome further insight on how to preserve maximal resource sharing for both of the use cases, template vs. non-template.

---

**edit:** I'm thinking that, for the purposes of the [sharability determination](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/TemplateContent.cs,46c60e62068b4a90) in template usage, the main difference between returning `this` (as I had originally suggested) and my revised suggestion to return `pvt.TargetObject` is that the former derives from `MarkupExtension`--versus the base class of `System.Windows.SharedDp` being `Object`--and it's clear that the probing code recurses into nested markup extensions.

Comment: I tried this myself before I even found this answer. And it does work during runtime. However in the designer I'm getting the error XLS0504 Property 'Text' does not support values of type 'MyBinding (BindingExpression)'. Have you had this issue?